# use mongo $slice operator with another operator

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have something like this below,

sample document

```
{
    series: [
        { scores: { value: 10 } }
    ]
}



$project: {
    x: { $slice: ['$series', -1] } }
},
{ $project: { x: { scores: 1 } } }
```

So from the series array, I want the last member object, then I only want the scores filed from that.  Actually scores.value but not sure how to get that either.
Is there a way to combine these together?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using the wrong operator to return the last object in the array. You need to [`$project`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/) your documents and use the [`$arrayElemAt`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/arrayElemAt/) to return the last object which you can set to a variable using the [`$let`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/let/) variable operator then use the [*dot notation*](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/document/#dot-notation) to address the "value" field.

```
db.collection.aggregate(
    [
        { "$project": {
            "value": { 
                "$let": { 
                    "vars": { "score": { "$arrayElemAt": [ "$series", -1 ] } },
                    "in": "$$score.value" 
                }
            }
        }}
    ]
)
```